# Drag item outside the scrollable container

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

So the "item" is draggable, but it disappears when I try to move it outside the **scrollable** container. I have tried with z-index but it does not seem to work. Any idea what could be wrong?

A working pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZaXVaE

```
body {
  background-color: lightyellow;
}

.container {
  height: 500px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: #ccc;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 9999;
}

<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    Move me
  </div>
</div>

$(".item").draggable({revert: true});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because `.container` has `overflow: scrooll`. This won't be visible with overflow like this

Comment: That's what I'm asking, I need to keep the scrolling but drag the item outside

Comment: As I've written - This won't be visible with overflow like this. I'm pretty sure you can't do this with scrolling

Comment: Is there then maybe some other way to keep the container to max height of 500px, add as many items as you want, and "scroll" somehow to see them all..?

Comment: I will try to do this. If I figure out how to do this, I will edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

Only one way to do this is to duplicate item in body and move this copied item.
Original item can be hidden till the end of moving.

```
$( ".item" ).clone().appendTo( "body" ).draggable({revert: true});
```

Or even better, use native functionality of draggable element

$( ".selector" ).draggable({
  helper: "clone"
});